# Are there rep-tiles with sharp points?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, fractals

Are there rep-tiles (shapes that can be dissected into smaller copies of the same shape) which contain sharp points on their boundary? By a sharp point, I mean a [cusp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)) on the boundary, a location where a point moving along the boundary must reverse direction. For example:

[image: A cusp]

Looking online, I cannot find any examples of rep-tiles with this property. There are plenty of rep-tiles with fractal boundaries, but I haven't seen any containing cusps.

For a rep-tile to have a cusp on it's boundary, it cannot be a polygon and it cannot be a convex shape. It seems to me that if the boundary is non-convex, then the kind of self-similarity it inherits from the rep-tile will force it to be fractal, but I don't know how to prove this.

The image of each cusp in each sub-tile will be a cusp or it will lie on the boundary between sub-tiles. If there are rep-tiles with cusps, they are much less "well-behaved" than ones without (with the exception of tiles with fractal boundaries).

So, are there rep-tiles with cusps on their boundaries?

Edit:
For $2$-d reptiles whose sub-tiles are not of identical size, there are no solutions.

If the rep-tile is not a polygon, but does not have a fractal boundary, then suppose there exists the point of maximum curvature $p$ of its boundary.

All images of $p$ will have curvature greater than $c$, so they cannot lie on the boundary of the rep-tile. Therefore, they must lie within the shape on the border between sub-tiles. They must meet with points of equal curvature, however different tiles have different scaling values, so they cannot meet with images of $p$. The largest image of $p$ must adjoin a point of equal curvature, but whose preimage has greater curvature than $p$, contradicting our assumption.

Can this be adapted for the case where all sub-tiles of the rep-tile are similar?
Can this be adapted for dimensions higher than $2$?

Comment: I don't think a rep-tile can have a curved boundary, because if its largest finite radius of curvature is $R$ then I don't see how a smaller copy could fit along the boundary where that curvature occurs. But that's just my guess.

Comment: @DavidK I understand your point, but I don't think there is always a well defined largest radius of curvature. For example, if the boundary curve moves from curved to straight with continuous first and second derivatives, then one can find points with arbitrarily large radii of curvature.

Comment: Yes, although note that when you scale down the rep-tile, not only the first derivative (curvature) needs to be matched but also all the other derivatives for the entire shared part of the boundary. I think this actually can be done but my hunch is you need infinitely many non-zero derivatives. And then you still have to match the rest of the original curve somehow with another scaled-down copy of the rep-tile; I suspect that's not possible.

Comment: @DavidK Could you expand on that further?
Also, I've thought further on your original point, and I think it is solvable using a similar approach, considering instead the point with the smallest radius of curvature.